# Solve error an't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/usr/local/zend/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock' (2) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs

Tags: mamp, mysql

I has problem with below error and  i spent many time to solve it.

Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/usr/local/zend/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock' (2) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs

This this are my environment MAC OSX 10.6.5 +  MAMP PRO 1.9.4 + ZendStudio

And this is solution to solve an error

1. create folder /usr/local/zend/mysql/tmp/ (if dose not exist)
2. use terminal and copy this : sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock /usr/local/zend/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock   then enter

** this error because zend can't find mysql.sock. so we need to create Alias for it.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to edit your mysql config file. You will find two sections in there, `mysqld` for the server `client` for the client app. The socket paths must be the same.

```
[mysqld]
...
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

[client]
...
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```